# Does anyone known the parametric equations for Cloud Gate?

Tags: calculus, parametric, mathematical-modeling

I would like to use Mathematica to plot the famous Chicago "Bean." I couldn't find parametric equations anywhere and was wondering if anyone knew them.

Thanks!

Comment: How accurate should the equations be? Are you talking about a 2D or 3D plot?

Comment: I would take anything at this point, but as accurate as possible.  3D plot.